# Why does my Apache rewrite rule to redirect http to https not work?

Tags: apache-2.4, rewrite

I'm trying to have a common rewrite rule so that all http traffic gets rerouted to https.

The following is sitting loose in the configuration

```
RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

But I'm still getting bad request, I'm speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.  I also tried with condition

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
```

Is it because rewrite rules must be contained with a virtual host?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the SSLEngine was implicitly turned on for the whole server, so that port 80 itself was expecting https! I created a wildcard virtual host and turned the engine off:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        SSLEngine Off
        TransferLog /var/log/apache2/http_access_log
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/http_error_log
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```